# Linux Bash Script - Want to run a stopwatch on console while performing other tasks

Tags: linux, bash

I have been pulling my hair out on this one. I am new to bash scripting and taking a Linux college class. This is not a requirement of any assignment, but just personal development.

I am trying to run a stopwatch on the console (showing the seconds as they tick by) while getting user input and doing other things.

I have researched this question for many hours. I think I am just searching with the wrong queries.

I have created a hangman game (where you guess the letters of word before guy is hung).

That was a great learning experience. Now I would like to have clock to indicate how much time has passed.

Any advice or links to relevant tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

My test code so far does not work but just does an infinite loop for timer.

```
#!/bin/bash
# timer.sh

timer ()
{
    while true
    do
    tput cup 0 0
    echo $SECONDS
    wait 1
    done
}

display ()
{
    tput cup 5 0
    echo -n "This is output from other stuff"
    read -n1 letter
    #while read -n1 letter
    #do
    tput cup 7 0

    echo -n "type any letter"
    tput cup 9 0
    echo -n "You letter is: $letter"
    if [[ "$letter" == "x" ]]
    then
        exit
    fi
    #done
}

finished ()
{
    tput clear
    echo -n "This is the end of the program"
    kill $timer_pid 
    exit
}

# Main Body

trap finished SIGINT SIGTERM
tput clear
while true
do
    timer &
    timer_pid=$!
    display 
done

exit
```

Comment: there have been at least 2 recent queries here on S.O. for a bash stopwatch; try searching for them. Good luck.

Comment: hey shellter, as I noted in my post I spent a lot of time. The S.O. posts that I came across regarding this issue did not answer my question. In the end it was just the wait 1 to sleep 1 as Dennis pointed out.

Comment: My apologies that I didn't read you posting closely enough. I'm glad there was a simple solution for you. Good luck to your future endeavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `wait 1` to `sleep 1`.

Comment: Thank you Dennis. It is crazy that that was the problem. I also took the 'timer &' and 'timer_pid=$!' out of the while loop, stopping it from continually spawning more shells. This is a basic script based on basic principles. Now on to learning how to do it a little more efficiently. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you are kind of familiar with shell scripting i am providing a basic logic. Moreover the more you code/read doc the more you learn, so not providing implementation.

```
Seconds=1
while true
do
    PrintWatch Seconds ## tput is an excellent option
    Seconds+=1
    Input=GetInputFromUserBlockFor_N_Seconds ## help read
    if Input == Stop
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# display time at line begin.
#
tick () {
  t=$(date +%T)
  echo -en "\r$t > " 
  sleep 10
  tick
}
tick
```

If you call this as a script with `./tick.sh &`, it will print the time at the beginning of the line always, but it will disturb your own input.

You may integrate the time into your prompt (see man: bash/ PROMPTING), but that will not actualize the time, just show the new time after every command you insert.